# Strictly increasing in $\mathbb Q$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

a) Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x)= x$ for every $x \in \mathbb Q$. Also presume that $f$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb R$ Show that $f(x)=x$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$.

b) Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x)= x$ for every $x \in \mathbb Q$. Also presume that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$ Show that $f(x)=x$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$.

Do I need to make a sequence $g(x)$ or what? I cant use density

Comment: You can't use density? Why not?

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant he has to use limits...which is the same as using density, of course.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.. Thanks for correction

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and note that $x$ is the least upper bound for $\{f(q): q\in\Bbb Q, q< x$, hence $f(x)\ge x$. However, consider $S_x = \{q\in\Bbb Q : q\ge x\}$ then by monotonicity, $S_x$ are all upper bounds for $f(x)$, in particular $f(x)\le \inf S_x = x$.

Similarly for continuity, you just note that (using continuity)

> $$x=\sup \{f(q) : q\in\Bbb Q, q < x\} = f(\sup \{q\in\Bbb Q : q < x\})=f(x)$$